# Conflicting lifetimes inside closure

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a trait for a `Decoder` that can return a packet that contains a reference inside. That is, I don't need to copy the packet to an owned object just so it's `'static`.

Here's the sketch:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub trait DecodedPacket<'a>: Send {}

pub type OnConsume = Arc<dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a mut Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket<'a>>>) + Send + Sync>;

pub trait Decoder: Send{
    fn receive_ref(&self,on_packet: Arc<dyn for<'a> FnMut(Box<dyn DecodedPacket<'a>>)>);
}

pub struct DummyDecoder {}

impl Decoder for DummyDecoder {
    fn receive_ref(&self,_: Arc<dyn for<'a> FnMut(Box<dyn DecodedPacket<'a>>)>){
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

struct DummyRenderer {
    on_consume: OnConsume
}

impl DummyRenderer {
    pub fn render(&self) {
        let mut decoded_packet: Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket<'_>>> = None;
        let packet = (self.on_consume)(&mut decoded_packet);
        //Render packet somehow here
    }
}

fn main() {
    let decoder: Box<dyn Decoder + Sync> = Box::new(DummyDecoder{});
    let renderer_on_consume: OnConsume =
        Arc::new(move |p: &mut Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket>>| {
            let decoded_packet: Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket>>>> = 
                Arc::new(Mutex::new(None));
            let on_packet = Arc::new(move |packet: Box<dyn DecodedPacket>|{
                decoded_packet.lock().unwrap().replace(packet);
            });
            decoder.receive_ref(on_packet);
            if let Some(packet) = *decoded_packet.lock().unwrap() {
                p.replace(packet);   
            }
        });
    let dummy_renderer = DummyRenderer{
        on_consume: renderer_on_consume
    };
    dummy_renderer.render();
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=89a181ae763d220199be91c9cb552e80

You can see that `receive_ref` expects a function that can deal with all lifetimes, so it should work for a small non `'static` lifetime. However, the compiler is making all the lifetimes `'static`:

Error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:35:58
   |
35 |             let decoded_packet: Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket>>>> = 
   |                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 34:18...
  --> src/main.rs:34:18
   |
34 |           Arc::new(move |p: &mut Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket>>| {
   |  __________________^
35 | |             let decoded_packet: Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket>>>> = 
36 | |                 Arc::new(Mutex::new(None));
37 | |             let on_packet = Arc::new(move |packet: Box<dyn DecodedPacket>|{
...  |
43 | |             }
44 | |         });
   | |_________^
note: ...but the lifetime must also be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 37:38...
  --> src/main.rs:37:38
   |
37 |               let on_packet = Arc::new(move |packet: Box<dyn DecodedPacket>|{
   |  ______________________________________^
38 | |                 decoded_packet.lock().unwrap().replace(packet);
39 | |             });
   | |_____________^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:42:27
   |
42 |                 p.replace(packet);   
   |                           ^^^^^^
   = note: expected `dyn DecodedPacket<'_>`
              found `dyn DecodedPacket<'_>`
```

ps: I don't like the `let decoded_packet: Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket>>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(None));` but I had to do it otherwise `decoded_packet` was getting borrowed by the closure and thus forcing the closure lifetime to be `'static`

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. The code is complicated and uses lifetime annotations in a way that doesn't make sense. e.g. you have a function type that takes no arguments and somehow returns a reference with an existential lifetime. The only way to resolve that is `'satic` - nothing to do with the Arc.

Comment: @PeterHall you're right, please look at my update, I changed that function so instead of returning something with a random lifetime, it now expects an `&mut Option<...>` with a lifetime, so it can alter this with the packet. The error is due to the 2 anonymous lifetimes inside the closure. And also I had to do `let decoded_packet: Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket>>>> = 
                Arc::new(Mutex::new(None));` which is kinda annoying. Otherwise the closures borrow the `decoded_packet` and thus they are forced to be `'static`

Comment: Why does `receive_ref` have to take an `Arc`?

Comment: @user3840170 because it could take different functions at runtime, so they would have different sizes. Does the `Arc` makes things difficult?

Comment: It kind of does: if `receive_ref` took a `&mut _` instead of an `Arc<_>`, it would simplify a lot. But without having a proper body for `receive_ref` I cannot tell if it’s a necessary complication or not. More generally, the question body doesn’t explain which design parameters are fixed and which are malleable well enough to make the question answerable.

Comment: @user3840170 the idea was to have a callback that can be changed in runtime, that's why I'm using an `Arc`. I could let it be a parameterized function if really needed, but I was trying with `Arc` first. Why do you say `&mut _` instead of `Arc` would simplify things?

Comment: Passing an `Arc` means that `receive_ref` owns the closure context and need not call it immediately. It may store the closure somewhere and call it arbitrarily late, long after `rendered_on_consume` is gone. Passing a `&mut dyn FnMut()` instead would (almost) allow the closure to call `p.replace` directly instead of doing awkward hoops through a `Mutex`. Why even take a closure in the first place? Can't you just return an `Option<Box<_>>`?

Comment: @user3840170 I wanted to be able to switch the decoder at any time. I don't see a way to do that if using generic type parameters. Some kind of runtime is needed. Ok, passing `&mut dyn FnMut()` is 'runtime' but would not work as it would capture the variable and force it to be `'static' I guess. About returning `Option<Box<>>`, is it possible to return something with a short lifetime? I thought the only way would be to pass a callback that consumes the short-lived variable

Comment: ‘it would capture the variable and force it to be `'static`’ – which one? Most importantly of all, why does `DecodedPacket` have a lifetime parameter?

Comment: @user3840170 @user3840170 `DecodedPacket` having a lifetime parameter is the important thing. For example, a video decoder might produce a video packet by giving a reference (a slice) to the buffer. So I put this reference inside `DecodedPacket`. If `DecodedPacket` does not have a lifetime parameter, then I'd have to copy this buffer to a vec just to pass to the renderer. About the other qurstion: the closure which captures `decoded_packet` would turn to be `'static`